# Why must a continuous function be null if its definite integral is null?

Tags: definite-integrals, continuity

Let $ f(x) = \begin{cases} f:[a,b] \rightarrow\mathbb R  \\ \int_{a}^{b}f = 0 \end{cases}$. Prove: if $f$ is continuous, then $f\equiv 0$.

I'm still trying to get the intuition on the situation. For instance, if $f(x) = sin(x), x \in {[0, 2\pi]}$, it's true that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}sin(x) = 0$, but it does not imply $sin(x) \equiv0$. What did I misinterpret here? After the understanding of the situation, I'd like to know how would a formal proof follow.

I'm a freshman Pure Math student who barely started the course and has very few practice in writing proofs, although slightly less worse at reading them. I'd like a level of rigor in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/148886/2) line of thought.

EDIT: as it is noticeable from the comments below, there is a condition missing in the statement: $f \geq0$.

Comment: Your example is right. The statement needs another assumption, namely that $f(x)\ge 0$ for $x \in [a,b].$

Comment: What is true is that if a **non-negative** continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\int_a^bf(x)dx=0$, then $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: Alternatively, if $f$ is continuous and $\int_{a}^{x}f = 0$ for every $x$ on $[a,b]$ then $f=0$ without assuming it non-negative.

Comment: As the comments above indicate, the property you are trying to prove is actually false, and your own counterexample shows it.  So something is being mis-copied.  What is the source of this statement -- is it from lecture notes, a textbook, or...?

Comment: My calculus professor asked it at the end of a class. He had then just asked a different question with a non-negative function, so he probably just forgot to repeat that condition for this question.

Comment: I've added the assumption to the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reasonably formal proof of the statement is:

Suppose that $f(x)\ge 0$ for $x\in [a,b]$, and that $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = 0$. Suppose further that there is some $c\in [a,b]$ with $f(c)>0$. Then by continuity, there is some open interval $(c_0,c_1)\subset [a,b]$ such that $f(x)>0$ for $x\in (c_0, c_1)$. Now consider any partition of $[a,b]$ such that one of the subintervals $[a',b']$ of the partition is contained in $(c_0,c_1)$. The Riemann sum associated with that partition consists of the areas of various rectangles; since $f\ge 0$ everywhere, each such area is nonnegative, and since $f$ is positive on $[a',b']$, the area of that rectangle, $A$, is $(b'-a')$ times the minimum value of $f$ on $[a',b']$. Therefore the Riemann sum is positive and is $\ge A$.

Now refine that partition so that the mesh approaches zero. Refinements of $[a',b']$ yield areas no less than $A$, while other rectangles remain nonnegative. Thus the area of any refinement is at least $A>0$, so that the integral is strictly positive.

It follows that $f$ must be zero everywhere on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P= \lbrace t_{1},...,t_{n} \rbrace  $ a partition of $[a,b]$ and suppose there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c) > 0$. Now, let $\epsilon > 0 $ such that $(c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon) \subset [t_{i},t_{i+1}]$ for some $i \in {1,...,n}$.

Thus, $\int_a^{b} f(x) dx = \underbrace{\int_a^{c-\epsilon}}_{\geq 0} + \underbrace{\int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon} f(x) dx}_{> 0} + \underbrace{\int_{c+\epsilon}^{b}f(x)dx}_{\geq 0} > 0$, which is contradiction since $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = 0$ by hypothesis.

Comment: This should be the main case, the other two come out trivialy